# write a c# program which accept a parameter as a particular date and give the output total number of days

Tags: c#

am using the code

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
int currentyear, currentmonth, borthmonth, birthyear, years, month;
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_age1.Text);
currentyear = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year);
currentmonth = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Month);
birthyear = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year);
borthmonth = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Month);
years = currentyear - birthyear;
if (currentmonth - borthmonth > 0)
{
    month = Convert.ToInt32(currentmonth - borthmonth);
}
else
{
    years = years - 1;
    month = Convert.ToInt32((12 - borthmonth) + currentmonth);
}
txt_age1.Text = years.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString();
```

but am getting this error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What input you are taking from Textbox name txt_age1.Text ?
i guess you are taking date of birth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i have checked it

```
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        int currentyear, currentmonth, borthmonth, birthyear, years, month;
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime("1993-08-04");//here i assume you are taking date of birth
        currentyear = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year);
        currentmonth = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Month);
        birthyear = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Year);
        borthmonth = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Month);
        years = currentyear - birthyear;
        if (currentmonth - borthmonth > 0)
        {
            month = Convert.ToInt32(currentmonth - borthmonth);
        }
        else
        {
            years = years - 1;
            month = Convert.ToInt32((12 - borthmonth) + currentmonth);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(years.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString());// here i am printing the result into console
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that entered string is in correct format. Since .NET can work with many cultures and each of them has different date and time formating, you have to be sure that string enterered by user and current culture fits. Please see samples in MS Articles [Convert.ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Convert.ToDateTime with Format provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There are two solutions:

1. You can add validation to your form (ie. regex)
2. You can split date enter process into 3 fields: Year, Month, Day and then create date object as

   ```
   var dt=new DateTime(year, month, day);
   ```

   see [DateTime constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Another thing is you can use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class instead subtracting dates on your own. It's as simply as:

```
var span=DateTime.Now - dt;
```